# Making object face the direction it is going in

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make the object face the direction it is moving in while moving it on a sphere, but instead of facing the direction, it rotates somewhat independently from the movement.

Here is what I have right now:

Code for object movement and rotation:

```
void Wander()
    {
        int rDirChange = Random.Range(0, 10);
        if (rDirChange > dChange)
        {
            mDirection = new Vector3((mDirection.x + Random.Range(-30, 30)), 0, (mDirection.y + Random.Range(-30, 30))).normalized;
            Vector3 tMovement = mDirection * moveSpeed;
            Movement = Vector3.SmoothDamp(Movement, tMovement, ref smoothMovement, 0.5f);
        }
        
    }

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position + (transform.TransformDirection(Movement) * Time.fixedDeltaTime));

    if (rotTimer > 60)
    {
        curPosition = transform.position;
        moveDirection = curPosition - oldPosition;
        oldPosition = curPosition;
        rotTimer = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        rotTimer += 1;
    }

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection), Time.deltaTime * 0.5f);
}
}
```

Code for attracted objects:

```
public void gravityAttractor(Transform body)
    {
        Vector3 targetDirection = (body.position - transform.position).normalized;
        Vector3 bodyUp = body.up;
        body.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(bodyUp, targetDirection) * body.rotation;
        body.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(targetDirection * gravity);
    }
```

Code for planet thing:

```
GravityAttractor Level;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        Level = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Level").GetComponent<GravityAttractor>();

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Level.gravityAttractor(transform);
    }
```

Comment: Why not lookat postion+direction

Comment: Why use `Quaternion.Slerp` for the rotation? And why this strange 60 FixedUpdate calls delay for refreshing the rotation target?

Comment: @BugFinder Maybe I was doing something wrong, but when I tried it my object started spazzing out. It worked fine when I tried it on a plane, tho.

Comment: @derHugo As you can guess, I am pretty new to this. Those were my attemps to fix the erratic rotation of the object. Now it is still not facing the direction it should, but at least it does not jitter as much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some general points first

- Stop using `GetComponent` repeatedly over and over again! Rather use it **once** and store the reference in order to reuse it later.
- whenever physics is involved you don't want to set any position or rotation via the `Transform` component at all as this breaks the physics and collision detection. Rather go through the `Rigidbody` component!
- then you shouldn't use `MovePosition` if additionally you want to add some forces since `MovePosition` would simply overrule the forces and velocity. You should rather simply set the `velocity` which then still allows to add additional forces.

Then getting the movement direction is as simple as

```
var direction = _rigidbody.velocity.normalized;
```

So I would rather use something like e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

private void Awake ()
{
    if(!_rigidbody) _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Wander()
{
    var rDirChange = Random.Range(0, 10);

    if (rDirChange <= dChange) return;
    
    mDirection = new Vector3((mDirection.x + Random.Range(-30, 30)), 0, (mDirection.y + Random.Range(-30, 30))).normalized;
    Vector3 tMovement = mDirection * moveSpeed;
    Movement = Vector3.SmoothDamp(Movement, tMovement, ref smoothMovement, 0.5f);

    _rigidbody.velocity = Movement;     
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Get the direction the Rigidbody is actually moving in
    var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(_rigidbody.velocity);
    _rigidbody.rotation = targetRotation;
    // Or if you still want to interpolate
    // _rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(_rigidbody.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it already seems to be better. There is another issue, tho, and it is connected to the gravity. The object seems to swap between absolute up and relative to planet up super fast.